# How to go back to first Android Fragment after replace

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I'm trying to get back to the first fragment after replacing it, but supportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate() do not work...

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.countries_list_activity)
        var colonCount = 1


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, CountriesFragment.newInstance(colonCount))
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit()
        }
    }

    override fun onListFragmentInteraction(item: Country?) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, CountriesListFragment.newInstance())
            .commit()

    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        supportFragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate()
    }
```

The function call order is OnCreate -> onListFragmentInteraction -> onBackPressed 
What i'm missing?

Comment: Welcome! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, especially “Help others reproduce the problem“, which is not easy right now. In particular, in what order are the functions above called?

Comment: OnCreate -> onListFragmentInteraction -> onBackPressed

Answer (score 1):

At starting i use popbackstack method but in this it iterate loop every time when back button is pressed. So i change my concept instead of popbackstack i maintain constant variable. and using this i manage my fragment. For that Follow Below Steps.

**Step 1:** make atleast two Global Variable.

```
    public static String currentTAG="HomeFragment";
    public static String AboutUsFragment="AboutUsFragment";
    public static String HelpfulTipsFragment="HelpfulTipsFragment";
```

**Step 2:** Change CurrentTag value when Fragment Open.

In Home Fragment in currentTAG=HomeFragment
similarly for **aboutUsFragment set CurrentTAG=AboutUsFragment;**

**Step 3:** Then After in Your main Activity Write down Below Code in Onbackpress method.

```
if (Const.currentTAG.equals(Const.HomeFragment)) {
            ExitApp();
        }else{
         getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.maincontainer, new HomeFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }


      private void ExitApp() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    builder.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.ask_before_close);
    builder.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    //final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            finish();

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

Similarly You Can Manage Multiple Fragment Without Iterating loop and popbackstack.

**NOTE:** When You Load Fragment Use Replace instead of add like below Code

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.maincontainer, new AboutAppFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```