# Android Studio open navigation Drawer using fragment and handle back button press

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i have create a navigation drawer using fragments which is working fine. The problem is when i click on back button in any fragment it it navigates me to login activity. how to handle the back button press in fragments??

Answer (score 0):

You have to override [onBackPressed().](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed())

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (this.drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        this.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Visit below Stackoverflow link where i put solution stepwise to handle multiple fragment on backpress.
[StackOverFlow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278288/how-to-go-back-to-first-android-fragment-after-replace/58281063#58281063)