# Update viewpager fragment specific position and get back to previous while backpress

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a view-pager with two fragment in it . based on my logic i want to replace the fragment on a specific position with another fragment but when user back-press i want to go back to previous fragment i replaced with it

**for clearance 
i have 4 fragment A, B, C, D   initially i added A and B to view-pager, then i replaced B with c in view-pager , So that i want  is to go back to fragment B (replaced by C) from C (current) while pressing back button instead of going back to another activity**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you can do using assign constant variable to your fragment or assign tag at time of Fragment Call.**

I manage using VariableName **CurrentFragment** which update value on Fragment Lunch. Then after onBackpress method of your activity i handle the fragment based on Constant Variable.

**Visit below Stackoverflow** link where i put solution step-wise to handle multiple fragment on backpress.

[Click Here to View StackOverFlowAnswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58278288/how-to-go-back-to-first-android-fragment-after-replace/58281063#58281063)